# How can I combine rule induction with variable generalization in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle, induction

In Isabelle, I can generalize variables in induction proofs using the `arbitrary` keyword. This definitely works for ordinary induction, like in `apply (induction n arbitrary: m)`. I can also have rule induction, like in `apply (induction rule: R.induct)`. But how can I generalize variables when using rule induction?

In my particular use case, I need to prove a theorem of the form `R x ⟹ S y  ⟹ ⟨…⟩`. The predicate `R` is inductively defined, and I want to use rule induction for it. The variable `y` cannot be fixed in the proof, but must be arbitrary. As a workaround, I have proved the theorem `R x ⟹ (∀ y . S y ⟶ ⟨…⟩)` instead, but I was not able to prove it without resorting to the sledgehammer, and I also guess that using `∀` and `⟶` here is not canonical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `arbitrary` and `rule` without a problem. However, the `arbitrary` has to appear before the `rule`.

Comment: I discovered this in the meantime. Before, I had tried to put the `arbitrary` after the `rule`. Very confusing that order matters here.